# Primitive recursive bounds for the the Gallai-Witt theorem

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Let me first recall some facts:

1. By the work of Gowers, the Van der Waerden numbers belong to class $\mathcal{E}^3$ of the [Grzegorczyk hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grzegorczyk_hierarchy#:%7E:text=The%20Grzegorczyk%20hierarchy%20(%2F%C9%A1r,and%20Wechsung%201986%3A43).)
2. By the work of Shelah, the Hales-Jewett numbers belong to class $\mathcal{E}^5$.

But there exists a higher dimensional version of the Van der Waerden theorem known as the Gallai-Witt theorem. As it follows from the Hales-Jewett theorem, so the corresponding numbers belong to class $\mathcal{E}^5$ as well.

**Question.** Is it known if the Gallai-Witt numbers belong to the class $\mathcal{E}^3$ or even $\mathcal{E}^4$?

If so, may you please provide a reference.